# Visual Studio deploy report item during build

Tags: c#, wpf, deployment, build, crystal-reports

I am working on a project that uses Crystal Reports WPF, so I have a report file (.rpt) that is required for the application to run properly. I am hoping that there is a way that I can set up visual studio to deploy this file to the bin whenever I do a build. I'd rather not have to set up a deployment project as an MSI seems kind of unnecessary for what this is.

Any thoughts are greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but can you just select the .rpt file in Solution Explorer and set `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy Always`?

Comment: <3 thank you. I can't believe I didn't know that was an option thats all I needed. Put this in as an answer and I will give you the points for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try just select the .rpt file in Solution Explorer and set `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy Always`